# Is there any chip that measures the amplitudes of voice bands simultaneously?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Is there any existing chip that can take 20Hz~20KHz signal as input and outputs the amplitude of each frequency band? For example, divide the 20Hz~20KHz range into few bands (20~1K, 1K~2K,...) and outputs all the power/amplitude of each band simultaneously?

Comment: Probably not and, stack exchange isn't about product recommendations so please take note.

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10468 - But this is off-topic.

Comment: @Andy: No problem, I understand it's not a good idea to find product recommendations here. Just want to know if such chip exists as I can't find any information about it by searching the Internet. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I suggest that you change your question to something like: "What would it take to output the amplitude of X frequency bands simultaneous." Besides the value of X you would also need to specify details like : the output format, precision, number of samples output per second and the separation you want between bands. As often: take a big enough FPGA and it can be done...

Comment: You appear to be looking for a spectrum analyzer for the audio band. such devices exist, often this function is implemented in a DSP.

Comment: @Oldfart: Thanks for your comment. Well, as I have tried hard to find such chip and failed, making the specification less specific may probably increase the possibility finding it. 
FPGA seems not attractive because I (as not an Digital Signal Processing expert) assume that only analog filters can generate real-time outputs, while DSP uses the data sampled in the past time (no matter how fast it samples).

Comment: @OliverChen you assume wrongly. analog filters have group delay, just like digital filters. There's no free lunch; math doesn't prefer the analog world. Anyway, you haven't even *specified* any maximum acceptable latency, so, I'd assume the filtering delay doesn't matter to you, at all. **write specs**, that's the only way forward here, as Oldfart correctly noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [Mix-Sig MSGEQ7](https://www.mix-sig.com/index.php/msgeq7-seven-band-graphic-equalizer-display-filter), a seven band filter, with centre frequencies of  63Hz, 160Hz, 400Hz, 1kHz, 2.5kHz, 6.25kHz and 16kHz. It outputs a DC signal for each band, stepped through by an external clock.

Comment: Although something with finer divided bands would be even better, actually this is the kind of chip I'm looking for.  Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Yeah, I love this chip. You can accomplish the same thing with several bandpass filters and a mux. This way you can tune the bands to whatever you'd like and have more than 7 channels.